# How to auto start service on Debian system?

Tags: shell, debian

I have a java application running as a service on Debian. How to I make sure this service is restarted after the system reboots?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the [documentation here](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon)

Debian makes use of System V-style init scripts for daemon management. This allows daemons to operate conditionally, based on the current RunLevel of the computer. For example, a daemon can be configured to run only when the computer is in single-user mode (runlevel 1) or, more commonly, when in multi-user mode (runlevels 2-5). For more information, see Init and RunLevel.